# $addToSet from my python code replace data instead of appending it

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I'm trying to save data in my collection using Pymongo.

```
port = 27017
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', port)
db   = conn.dbcoll
newReservationId ="Value change from front-end"
customerData = { 'firstName':"Jamesss", 'lastName':"Jamesss" }
db.person.update({'_id':'1223'},  customerData )
db.person.update({'_id':'1223'},  {"$addToSet":{"reservationList":newReservationId }} ) 
conn.close()
```

Every time the field "reservationList" get overwrite by the new value "newReservationId". It is suppose to append the new value "newReservationId" in the array.

Can anyone please let me know why  $addToSet doesn't work the way it is suppose to ?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Your `$addToSet` isn't the problem, it's the `update` before it that's overwriting the whole object.  Use a `$set` to just update those two `customerData` fields:

```
db.person.update({'_id':'1223'}, {"$set": customerData} )
db.person.update({'_id':'1223'}, {"$addToSet":{"reservationList":newReservationId }})
```

Better yet, combine both updates into one:

```
db.person.update({'_id':'1223'}, {
    "$set": customerData,
    "$addToSet":{"reservationList":newReservationId }
})
```

Comment: Yes Yes I figure it out. the issue was the first update. Thanks for your input. Cheers!

Comment: Great! If this resolved your question, click the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it answered.